# Physical interpretation of a wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Do exist any physical interpretation of (several) boundary conditions like :

$$y=g_1\ne 0,\; \Delta y=g_2,\; ..=\Delta^{k-1} y =g_k,\;
\mbox{on} \; \partial \Omega,\; k\ge 2$$

for the wave equation $$y_{tt}=\Delta y + a(x) y + b(x)y_t, \;\mbox{in}\; 
\Omega\times (0,T)?$$

Comment: Since the equation is second order, you can only specify so many different derivatives. In fact, I think specifying y on $\partial \Omega \times (0,T)$ and initial data completely determine your solution, so no, it wouldn't be particularly meaningful.